# Filter out words from string with Sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, replace, sqlite

After I run a specific query I obtain a string that matches the name of an investment fund like 'GS Gbl Sov Bd Ptf Base Cap' stored in a list.

What I would like to do is to filter out specific words from the query like 'Cap' and 'Ptf' to obtain the "basic" fund name such as 'GS Gbl Sov Bd Base'.

When I try to use the replace method it gives me the error : 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' or if I try to convert it in a string it just won't recognise certain blacklisted words.

Is there a smarter way to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Show us the relevant code, or better yet, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete error message. Also this question does have nothing to do with sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add more detail about your problem and post your code attempt :

From this example you can take hint :

if from each query you are getting a list and it have one item then :

```
your_list=['GS Gbl Sov Bd Ptf Base Cap']
stop_words=['Cap','Ptf' ]

final_list=[]
for i in your_list[0].split():
    if i not in stop_words:
        final_list.append(i)

print(" ".join(final_list))
```

output:

```
GS Gbl Sov Bd Base
```

You can do in one line too:

```
print(" ".join([i for i in your_list[0].split() if i not in stop_words]))
```

output:

```
GS Gbl Sov Bd Base
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert the list into a set, and remove another set containing the words you want to filter out.

```
data = ["GS", "Gbl", "Sov", "Bd", "Ptf", "Base","Cap"]
data = set(data)

filter_words = set(["Cap","Whatever"])

filtered_data = data - filter_words
```